# Arguments to ARM Linux's arm_pm_restart()

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I am trying to hook in functionality for the following kernel API:

```
extern void (*arm_pm_restart)(enum reboot_mode reboot_mode, const char *cmd);
```

- [arch/arm/include/asm/system_misc.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/system_misc.h#L14)
- I would like to know what is the use of the second parameter **char *cmd**.
- I am unable to rationalize the need for the second parameter **cmd**, though the first parameter **reboot_mode** makes proper sense...

Can someone please explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know what is the use of the second parameter `char *cmd`.
>   Can someone please explain ?

This is called via [`machine_restart()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/process.c?id=refs/tags/v3.12-rc7#n233), which is in turn called by [`kernel_restart()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/reboot.c?id=refs/tags/v3.12-rc7#n125).  As per the kernel doc,

> @cmd: pointer to buffer containing command to execute for restart or %NULL

You can pass a command to [*reboot*](http://linux.die.net/man/2/reboot)<sup>note</sup> and this is what you see.  For the most part, ARM hooks just ignores it.  You could check it for `NULL` or also ignore it.

From `man 2 reboot`,

> The  precise  effect  of  the  above  actions  depends  on  the architecture. For the i386 architecture, the additional argument does not do anything at present (2.1.122), but the type of reboot can be determined by kernel command-line arguments ("reboot=...") to be either warm or cold, and either  hard  or  through  the BIOS.

You are free to ignore it, but you could use it if you needed user space to signal something special.  Almost always, you will get `cmd == NULL`.

**Note:** This command always returns with *failure*; it shouldn't return ;-)  See the define `LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART2` for the case that this `cmd` is non-NULL.